# Why does window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart return 0

Tags: javascript, window-object

Below is my js function code.

```
console.log(window.performance.timing);
console.log(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart);
```

When i run the above code by running my `js file`, `window.performance.timing` returns an `object` in which `domContentLoadedEventStart` has some value. But when i tried to print `window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart` it returns 0.

Not sure what is happening. Can somebody explain me.

Comment: On what platform did you execute the code?

Comment: @K_58: By including the js file in my html file.

Comment: What version does your browser have? If you're using _Chrome_, check it with `chrome://version`.

Comment: @K_14: yes. I use chrome v61.0.3163.100

Comment: **Type (don't copy-paste)** `console.info(JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing), JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart));` on your developer console (`F12`) and show me the result, please.

Comment: @K_2: {"navigationStart":1508837331988,"unloadEventStart":1508837332029,"unloadEventEnd":1508837332029,"redirectStart":0,"redirectEnd":0,"fetchStart":1508837331993,"domainLookupStart":1508837331998,"domainLookupEnd":1508837331998,"connectStart":1508837331998,"connectEnd":1508837332001,"secureConnectionStart":0,"requestStart":1508837332001,"responseStart":1508837332019,"responseEnd":1508837332027,"domLoading":1508837332040,"domInteractive":0,"domContentLoadedEventStart":0,"domContentLoadedEventEnd":0,"domComplete":0,"loadEventStart":0,"loadEventEnd":0} 0

Comment: Try putting your `<script>` tag to the (inner) bottom of the `<body>`. Does it give still `0`?

Comment: @K_3: Yes. Still it returns 0 only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157359/discussion-between-k-and-user2613946).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `window.performance.timing`

This property has a `PerformanceTiming` object describing your page.

## `PerformanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventStart`

The `PerformanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventStart` property has a value representing the moment **right before the parser sent the `DOMContentLoaded` event**, in miliseconds since the UNIX epoch.

## `DOMContentLoaded` event

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

## The reason why `window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart` gave you `0`

Your script was executed before the `DOMContentLoaded` event occurred, so the moment right before the parser sent the `DOMContentLoaded` event, **was unknown at that time.**

[image: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html]

## To prevent it

To prevent `PerformanceTiming.domContentLoadedEventStart` from being `0`, you have to refer it after the `DOMContentLoaded` event occurs. Try this one:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    console.info("DOM fully loaded and parsed.");
    console.info(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart);
});
```

or

```
<script defer src="...">
```

.

Comment: It throws error in IE. Syntax error at document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {... But it works well in other browsers. Pbm with 'event'

Comment: @user2613946 It seems your IE does not support _Arrow functions_. Try using `function(event) {` instead of `event => {`.